# How to Inner join with @ManyToMany created Table in entity ( Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use the H2 database and spring boot for this task, I have two entities.
The First entity is:

```
public class e1{
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "t12",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "e1_ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "e2_ID")})
    private Set<Game> listSet1 = new HashSet<>();
}
```

The second entity is:

```
public class e2{

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "listSet1")
    private Set<Player> listSet2 = new HashSet<>();

}
```

After running the application we have a table called "t12".

Now, I have a question, I would like to know, How to join with this table I mean ( @JoinTable t12) without an entity from the e2 class.

I mean, when we are running an application Spring use this annotation @JoinTable to create a table for two entities. Now after created this table I want to join with them. but the table ( I mean @JoinTable name "X") has no entity. I want to use Inner join with this table and one of my entities.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you need to do?

Spring Data JPA lets you write native SQL queries using the `@Query` annotation with `nativeQuery = true`.

e.g. In your Repository interface, you can try something like:

```java
@Query(
  value = "SELECT * FROM e1 INNER JOIN t12 ON t12.e1_ID = e1.id WHERE t12.e2_ID = :e2ID",
  nativeQuery=true)
Collection<e1> findAllByE2ID(Long e2ID);
```

Some useful resources:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_native_queries
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query#2-native
- https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-data-jpa-many-to-many-mapping

Please take a look at some naming conventions in java and Spring Boot:

- https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html
- https://www.baeldung.com/java-class-file-naming
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-custom-naming